# How to get the value of radio button in Zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

This is my form, I have a radio button from 1 to 5 (very bad to very good)

```
    parent::__construct($name);

    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
        'name' => 'rate_box',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Please choose your rate',
            'value_options' => array(
                '1' => ' Very Bad',
                '2' => ' Bad',
                '3' => ' Fine',
                '4' => ' Good',
                '5' => ' Very Good',
            ),
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => '1' //set checked to '1'
        )
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'type' => 'Submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'submit',
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
        ),
    ));
```

This is the related part of my controller

```
        $form = new VoteForm();

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost())
        {
            $form->setData($request->getPost());
            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $formdata = $form->getData();
                $vote = new Vote();
                $data = $vote->getArrayCopy();
                $data['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $data['voted_user_id'] = $voted_user_id;
                $data['ratescore'] = $formdata['rate_box']; //Here I take the value of radion button

                $vote->populate($data);
                try
                {
                    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($vote);
                    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home',array('user_id' => $user_id,
                                                              'action' => 'home',
                    ));
                }
                catch(DBALException $e){

                }
            }
        }
```

Why I can't retrieve the value of "rate_box" and save to my $data['ratescore']?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this problem few hours ago. You can try to retrieve the value of radio button using the native $_POST['rate_box'] in your action.
So, in your controller :

```
    public function yourAction() {
        $form = new VoteForm();
        if($this->getRequest->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest->getPost();
            if($form->isValid($data)) {
                $rate = $_POST['rate_box'];
                // another code..
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.. :)